# PyCharm 2017.2.4: How to pass --nologcapture or any other command line argument to nosetest runner?

Tags: python, logging, pycharm, nose

How can I pass the `--nologcapture` argument to nosestest in the new PyCharm 2017?

In the old 2016 version the `Params` field could be used:

[image]

This is gone in 2017 and has been replaced by `Additional Arguments`:

[image]

However, adding `--nologcapture` there has no effect whatsoever.

So, how can I disable the logcapturing in nostests with PyCharm 2017?
In general, how can I pass command line arguments to nose with the new PyCharm?